# Example for a physical distribution without a well-defined standard deviation

Tags: statistics

Is there a physical example of a distribution that has a diverging standard deviation (like the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution)) and is there an intuitive reason for the standard deviation diverging?

Is there a physical context where I should expect my standard deviation to be not well-defined?

Answer (score 3):

The standard deviation is one example of a metric to characterize the width probability distributions. There is no particular physical meaning to the standard deviation diverging, in general; you just need to use a different measure of the width of the distribution. It is just a mathematical tool, that is useful in some contexts, and not others.

The Cauchy distribution is also called a Lorentzian distribution in physics, and appears very frequently in characterizing modes of a system with dissipation in classical mechanics, or unstable particles that decay (also called resonances) in quantum mechanics. It arises naturally when you solve the equation for a [damped, driven harmonic oscillator](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves/node13.html) in Fourier space (compare Eq 120 in the notes I linked to with the first equation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Probability_density_function)). The fact that the standard deviation of the Lorentzian diverges poses no problem to using this distribution in those contexts. Often, the width of a Lorentzian is characterized in terms of the [full width at half maximum (FWHM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum).